# Zillow Zestimate xml data

Tags: xml, api, zillow

I am working with Zillow Zestimate and trying to get some data from it. I have a form that collects the customer's current address.

What I need to know is how do I call the API with the API key that I received and then once I am able to get the `XML` data. How do I post it on my web page after it's sent back?

[Here](http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=%3CMY%20ID%3E8&address=123%20anywhere%20ave&citystatezip=seattle%20Wa) is the link to the API call :

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: @RafH Please don't make suggested edits that include broken links. Please try to to fix everything that needs fixing.

Answer (score 6):

I came across this because I started using Zillow this morning.  The Zillow API is surprisingly easy which might be why I haven't found a step-by-step tutorial yet.

First, here's the URL to where I got my information: http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetZestimate.htm

Next, you'll need to register and get a ZWSID.  It took me about 5 minutes to register and less than a minute to get a response from Zillow with my ZWSID

To do your first query, take this 'http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetZestimate.htm?zws-id=&zpid=48749425' and replace  with your own ID.  Then copy and paste the edited URL into a browser or Fiddler and execute the query.

If you want to query a specific address put a '-' instead of a space.  So the URL would look something like this: http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=&address=123-Main-Street&citystatezip=55555

I will always have the zip and they query will work if you only provide the zip code.  It will also work if you just provide the city and state. (Remember to replace the space with a '-')

I have found that abbreviations and spelling the complete word works. For example: 123-Main-St and 123-Main-Street worked equally as well.

As an FYI, the API only returns XML and not JSON. (http://www.zillow.com/advice-thread/Is-there-a-way-to-get-API-data-in-JSON-format-If-not-is-there-any-plan-to-add-JSON-as-an-option/494343/)

So I think that answers the first part of your question.

For the second part, I would suggest that you create a new question.  I think you'll get a lot more answers if you narrow down the question you're asking. As it is, it's a really broad question and would require a lot more information.  Starting with more detail about the environment you're developing in: ASP.net, PHP, where will the query be executed etc.

Comment: Are you sure you can query by zip only? I get error when I omit the address `Error: no address specified`

Comment: I haven't worked with that API in about a year, but I believe I meant you don't need address, city, state, and zip. Instead, merely address and zip will work.

Comment: Is zillow only enough to build a realestate website it seems I need to use idx/mls do u know anything about that. Even if i dont put the house number zillow cannot find anything

Comment: I don't actively use Zillow so I'm not sure what it's full capabilities are.  The API call I was testing was to fetch an estimated home value.  For a full website, you'd need a lot more features than that...

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question too late, but may be it could help someone.

Here is the link to the Zillow tutorial written in PHP.

```
http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2014/03/20/getting-started-with-zillow-api/
```